# Attach debugger to Firebase Python Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, vscode-debugger, firebase-tools

I'm using the emulator to run cloud functions with Python. I'd like to attach a debugger using VS Code. This is easy when using Node, I just need to pass the `--inspect-functions` flag in when starting the emulator:

```
firebase emulators:start --project demo-project --inspect-functions
```

Here is my vscode launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Firebase Cloud Functions",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

Now clicking <kbd>F5</kbd> is vscode will attach the debugger.

When running Python functions, I get this warning in emulator logs:

```
functions --inspect-functions only supported for Node.js runtimes.
functions --inspect-functions not supported for Python functions. Ignored.
```

How do I attach the debugger to Python cloud functions with Firebase?

Comment: This might be a feature request that you should file with [firebase-tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools).

Comment: Created this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/6838